# how to insert null or valid value in nullable column of database in EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework

I am in scenerio where I need to inset a dateTime value in the database using the EF 4.1.
 DateColumn in database in Nullable.

While creating the entity i am filling it as,

```
 DTCLOSE = referenceProblemLog.DateClosed.HasValue ? 
            referenceProblemLog.DateClosed.Value.ToFeedFormatString() : 
            System.DBNull.Value.ToString(),
```

where ToFeedFormatString is an extension method.

Now problem i observed is, if I have a proper value then it is inserted correctly but
**when i dont have a proper date value, i want to insert NULL in database column. However EF is saving column with Empty string**

I tried to change the StoreGeneratedPattern for the field to "Identity" but problem with it is, I cant assign value to DTCLose field.

How can i have both the things?
1. EF should insert NULL in database when proper value is not there
2. proper value otherwise

Please help

Thanks
Anup

Comment: System.DBNull.Value.ToString() seems odd, try just use null instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong `System.DBNull.Value.ToString()` because at the end you will have string object, ToString() never returns null.

You have to set `DTCLOSE = null`

Also, with EF you don't have to use `DBNull`, you just define nullable property and set it `null`

Comment: How do you define nullable property?

Comment: `int? property;` question mark after structural type makes it nullable

Answer (score -2):

You Can use this :

```
 Nullable<DateTime> date=null;
 var entity = new Model()
            {
                GoDate = date
            };

DataContext.Models.Add(entity);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```